# A morphism of complex affine schemes which is bijective on complex points but is not an isomorphism.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I am trying to find some such examples:

A morphism of complex affine schemes which is bijective on complex points but is not an isomorphism.

May I please ask for some examples, if possible. I would like to know how to construct such an example and how to think about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JohnMa The map you describe is not bijective. $1,\omega$ where $\omega^3=1$ both go the same point. The standard example of such a phenomenon is $\mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{A}^2$, given by $t\mapsto (t^2,t^3)$, the image is the cuspidal curve $x^3=y^2$.

Comment: And since you asked about how to think about this example, it's actually enough to import the fact/intuition that this is a bijection-but-not-isomorphism of smooth manifolds, since an isomorphism of schemes would induce an isomorphism of tangent spaces at every point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a completely different flavor of counterexample.

Let $X = \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}(x))$. Then $X$ is an affine scheme over the complexes, but $X(\mathbb{C}) = \varnothing$ — it has no points at all with $\mathbb{C}$ as the residue field!

With the basic idea, it's easy to see how to construct lots of counterexamples.

Answer (score 2):

**A bijection on complex points, but not a homeomorphism**, as it is the case for the canonical bijection $\mathrm{Spec} \mathbb{C}\bigsqcup \mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$. More generically, you can take an *irreducible* complex scheme $X$, an open subscheme $U\subset X$ with a complementary closed subscheme $V$, and consider the canonical morphism $V\bigsqcup U\to X$.

**A [universal homeomorphism](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04DC), but not an isomorphism**, as it is the case for the normalisation of the cuspidal curve, mentioned in Mohan's comment. Also, the closed immersion of the maximal reduced closed subscheme $X_{\mathrm{red}}\to X$, for every *non-reduced* complex affine scheme $X$ provides such an example. The discussion on universal homeomorphisms [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BR5) and [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05Z3) might also be useful in constructing such examples.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more ad-hoc example: consider the morphism $f:\operatorname{Spec}(B) \to  \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ where:

$$ A = \mathbb{C}[x, x^{-1}] $$
$$ B = \mathbb{C}[y, y^{-1}] $$

and the morphism is induced by $x \to y^2$.

Geometrically, $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is the complex line with the origin removed, and $\operatorname{Spec}(B)$ is the double cover corresponding to the graph of the multi-valued function $\sqrt{x}$.

On maximal ideals, $f$ is precisely a 2-1 function. Let $S$ be any multiplicative subset of $B$ generated by the generators of exactly one ideal per pair; e.g. you can let $S$ be the set of all functions whose roots all have complex argument in $[0, \pi)$.

Then if we form the localization of $B$ by inverting the elements of $S$, the restriction $\operatorname{Spec}(S^{-1} B) \to \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is bijective on points, and bijective on complex points.